# highlight and remove highlight the div on click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, highlight

I have below code in my rails app

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
<div class="divs" data-slide-block-id="#task-drawer">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-3">
   <h5 class="pd0">
    <%= completed.nil? ? '' : '<i class="taskedit_completed_icon fa fa-check text-success icon mr-5"></i>'.html_safe %>
    <%= t["item"]%>
   </h5>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
   <h5 class="pd0">
     <%= @stages.select{|s| s["id"] == t["stage_id"]}.map{ |s| s["name"] }.first || "n/a" %>
   </h5>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3" style="margin-left:40px;">
   <h5 class="pd0" style="font-size: 18px; color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold;">
       &#x3e;
   </h5>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want to highlight a div when click on it and de-highlight when click on it again. I have below javascript.

```
<style>
.color {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

 <script>
   var addclasss = 'color';
   var $cols = $('.divs').click(function(e) {
       $cols.removeClass(addclasss);
       $(this).addClass(addclasss);
 });

 </script>
```

When I click on div it become highlight and task drawer shows up. But with second click I can't de-highlight it but task drawer disappear.I have to click again to de-highlight.But with this third click again task drawer shows up.I want to de-highlight the div when task drawer disappear .How can I solve this? I attached the screen shot herewith.

[image]

Comment: did you try using `toggle` function

Comment: @RohitAmbre I tried. but it is not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggleClass('color')`:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#example').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('color');
    });
});
```

```css
#example {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 20px;
}

.color {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before. But it is not working for my case

Comment: Looking a little closer at your code, I think you want to do: `$cols.not(this).removeClass(addclasss);
       $(this).toggleClass(addclasss);`